# recompress useing python and zlib

Tags: python, zlib, compression

I am trying to decompress a file make some changes and than compress it again. Decompressing seems to work fine. I just need a method to compress it so it is compressed the same way it was before.

Here is my code:

```
import zlib

path = './input'
pathOut = './output'

def getInt(intArray):
    summe = 0
    for i in range(len(list(intArray))):
        summe += intArray[i]*256**i
        return(summe)


print(path)
inputfile = open(path, 'rb')
header = {}

header.update({"intro":inputfile.read(28)})
print("intro",(header["intro"]))

for key in ["header_size", "c_size", "header_v", "u_size", "blocks"]:
    header.update({key:inputfile.read(4)})
    print(key,getInt(header[key]))


inputfile.seek(getInt(header['header_size']))

blocks_count = getInt(header['blocks'])
data = []
for i in range(blocks_count):
    block_header = {}
    block_header.update({"c_size":inputfile.read(2)})
    print("c_size",getInt(block_header["c_size"]))
    block_header.update({"u_size":inputfile.read(2)})
    print("u_size",getInt(block_header["u_size"]))
    block_header.update({"checksum":inputfile.read(4)})
    print("checksum",getInt(block_header["checksum"]))
    temp = inputfile.read(getInt(block_header['c_size']))[2:-4]
    data.append(zlib.decompressobj().decompress(b'x\x9c' + temp))
output = b''
inputfile.seek(0)
output = inputfile.read(getInt(header["header_size"]))
inputfile.close()

compressor = zlib.compressobj(1)

for block in data:
    compressor.compress(block)
    output += compressor.flush(zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)

print("output length",len(output))
print("c_size",getInt(header["c_size"]))
outputFile = open(pathOut, 'wb')
outputFile.write(output)
outputFile.close()
```

When I try to decompress my output it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\LSDesktop\Desktop\bla - Copy.py", line 45, in <module>
        data.append(zlib.decompressobj().decompress(b'x\x9c' + temp))
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
```

here are the first 50 bytes including the header of the first block. Ones how they should be (how they were before I compressed):

```
b'B\x0c\x00 rWfyx\x01\xacY\tX\x14G\x16\xae\x9e)p\x00\r\x18\x15\xb9Lk\xc7\x03\xaf\x88\x1a\x8c\x0c\xa8\x084(\x82\x17\x87\x17\x88\xa3\x8c\x1c;r\x0b'
```

and the first 50 bytes including the header of the first block after the I compressed it:

```
b'\xacY\tX\x14G\x16\xae\x9e)p\x00\r\x18\x15\xb9Lk\xc7\x03\xaf\x88\x1a\x8c\x0c\xa8\x084(\x82\x17\x87\x17\x88\xa3\x8c\x1c;r\x0b\x82&\nk4\x1c\x89fQ\x89'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Z_FINISH` instead of `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`.  You are decompressing separate zlib streams, but you then try to make a new single zlib stream that is never terminated.  To make separate zlib streams, you need to use `Z_FINISH` each time.  You must use `Z_FINISH` at least once at the end, or you will never generate a proper zlib stream.

As for the wrappers around that, if you are attempting to write out the same format you read in, you're not doing that.  You need to recreate the header information, i.e. the lengths and checksums.  Where is this format documented?  Did you copy the code to read the input from somewhere else?

This is not the problem, but you should not be stripping the zlib header and trailer with `[2:-4]`, and then adding a header back with `b'x\x9c' +`.  In order to decompress. Just decompress the zlib stream directly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Setting aside the fact that no question was asked, that does provide an answer.  How is "Try Z_FINISH instead of Z_SYNC_FLUSH." critiquing or asking a question?

Comment: Well if I just replace "Z_SYNC_FLUSH" by "Z_FINISH" i tells me: "zlib.error: Error -2 while compressing data: inconsistent stream state" And if I only do that for the last block I get the same error as before.